# How to set up DNS encryption on my home router?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, openwrt

I set up OpenWRT on my Belkin RT3200 and I want to have quad9 encrypted DNS with dnssec and Secure SNI, but I could not figure out how to set up DNScrypt correctly on my router and I'm not sure if that's the best method.

I'd like to avoid my DNS info going to google and cloudflare even if encrypted. I'd also like to force all DNS to use this encryption so there are no leaks when I use a VPN on one of my devices.

Can someone help me with a step-by-step guide or point me in the right direction?

Comment: welcome, you've stated your goal of avoiding cloudflare and google dns which is helpful - if you can, please edit your question to include what steps you've already taken - feel free to include a diagram, the relevant bits from config file/s, etc

Comment: ps. the only way you can make a client use a particular dns is to configure the client in that manner - i can instal a web browser on your device that will use cloudflare dns-over-https exclusively for all browsing regardless of your dhcp settings (with a couple of simple configuration changes)

Comment: @brynk User was already advised to improve question, when it landed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74537473/what-is-the-most-secure-way-todo-encypted-dns-on-my-rt3200-openwrt-router?noredirect=1  but it is unfortunately here just a copy and paste and seems as offtopic here as on SO.

Comment: The OpenWrt homepage has guides for this. Tried any of those yet?